# Talking to MAX31865 from Raspberry Pi using Serial Peripheral Interface

Tags: pi-2, python-3, spi

I am trying to talk to the [MAX31865](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX31865.pdf) board from a Raspberry Pi over SPI but am not getting the results I'd expect. Can someone with more SPI experience take a look at my setup and point to what I may be doing wrong?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sys

CLK = 11
MISO = 9
MOSI = 10
CS = 8
DRDY = 22

def setupSpiPins(clkPin, misoPin, mosiPin, csPin, drdyPin):
    GPIO.setup(clkPin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(misoPin, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(mosiPin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(csPin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(drdyPin, GPIO.IN)

def readAdc(channel, clkPin, misoPin, mosiPin, csPin, drdyPin):
    GPIO.output(csPin, GPIO.HIGH)

    print(GPIO.input(drdyPin))

    GPIO.output(csPin, GPIO.LOW)

    #read first 8 bits
    read_command = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    sendBits(read_command, 8, clkPin, mosiPin)
    adcValue1 = recvBits(8, clkPin, misoPin)

    #read second 8 bits
    read_command = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
    sendBits(read_command, 8, clkPin, mosiPin)
    adcValue2 = recvBits(8, clkPin, misoPin)

    print(adcValue1)
    print(adcValue2)

    GPIO.output(csPin, GPIO.HIGH)

    return 0

def sendBits(data, numBits, clkPin, mosiPin):
    for bit in range(numBits):
        GPIO.output(clkPin, GPIO.HIGH)

        if data[bit] == 1:
            GPIO.output(mosiPin, GPIO.HIGH)
        else:
            GPIO.output(mosiPin, GPIO.LOW)

        GPIO.output(clkPin, GPIO.LOW)

def recvBits(numBits, clkPin, misoPin):
    retVal = []

    for bit in range(numBits):
        GPIO.output(clkPin, GPIO.HIGH)

        if GPIO.input(misoPin):
            retBit = 1
        else:
            retBit = 0

        retVal.append(retBit)

        GPIO.output(clkPin, GPIO.LOW)

    return retVal

try:
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    setupSpiPins(CLK, MISO, MOSI, CS, DRDY)

    while True:
        val = readAdc(0, CLK, MISO, MOSI, CS, DRDY)
        print('ADC Result: ' + str(val))
        time.sleep(5)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
    sys.exit(0)
```

According to the datasheet I linked too above you perform 2 reads with 8 bits representing the registers you want to read and then it returns 8 bits for each read you performed. At this stage I am just trying to confirm that I am getting different data results but I am getting an array of all 0 and all 1.

So I am sending bits [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], and [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0] and receiving arrays [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] and [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1].

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason to bit bang the SPI protocol?  Your job is likely to be simpler if you use the standard SPI driver.  Perhaps use the Python spidev module.

Comment: I thought I would understand turning bits on and off better this way. No, there is not a hard requirement to bit bang the SPI protocol.

Comment: Fair enough.  I haven't looked at the device specs but I doubt you send 8 bits then read 8 bits.  As you send each bit you need to read a bit.  See https://microcontrollerslab.com/introduction-to-spi-communication-protocol/

Comment: I must be misunderstanding SPI then because the datasheet strongly implies I have to send 8 bytes followed by reading 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

SPI (Serial Peripheral Interface) is simply a shift register where you clock data in the first stage and the output of the last stage is on the output pin. Each time you clock it it takes the data in the register and shifts it down one. The last bit is dropped then the output then has the data from the previous stage. It can get confusing with the clock phases and polarity.

The SPI interface, full duplex, was developed 1985 by Motorola where it was implemented initially in there 68HCO5 family and the 68HC11 microprocessor familys. It expanded from there. This was a simple and inexpensive way to expand the number of input and output pins on the microprocessors. The external devices could be simple logic family shift registers. Data was synchronous to keep transfers short and fast.

There are four connections required. They are MISO (Master In Slave Out), MOSI (Master Out Slave In) CLK, and CS\ Chip Select. The default size of the shift registers is 8 bits (the HC05 and HC11 are 8 bitters) but there is no limit, it can be as many or as few a bits the user wants to implement.

The clock is generated by the master and used by the slaves to synchronize the data. You need to contend with Clock polarity (CPOL) and clock phase (CPHA), these are the main parameters that define a clock format to be used by the SPI bus. CPHA parameter is used to shift the sampling phase. If CPHA=0 the data are sampled on the leading (first) clock edge. If CPHA = 1 the data is sampled on the back porch. Depending on the CPOL parameter, SPI clock may be either inverted or non-inverted.

SPI is a synchronous serial communication interface because it has a clock that controls the timing on the sending where (master, sending unit) generates the clock and the receiving end uses this to transfer data to its input and cause its registers to shift.

This leaves the “BOS” pin, chip select. All peripheral devices will ignore whatever is happening on the MISO, MOSI, and CLK unless they are selected. You can connect the peripherals (depending on type) in serial or parallel. Generally they are connected in parallel then the CS\ pin is used to select the desired device. The 4HC138 was a common chip used to generate 8 chip selects from only 3 pins.